# How can i install ashmem on Ubuntu 24.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android, kernel-module

I just installed Anbox on Ubuntu 23.10 but it doesn't work (app manager stuck on Starting... screen with Anbox icon and then crashing after about 1 minute) because there isn't ashmem, I only see that i have binder right now, but it seems like i don't if I look at `anbox system-info`.

```
 $ ls -1 /dev/{binderfs,ashmem}
ls: cannot access '/dev/ashmem': No such file or directory
/dev/binderfs:
anbox-binder
anbox-hwbinder
anbox-vndbinder
binder-control
features
```

```
$ anbox session-manager
[ 2024-03-16 18:17:58] [session_manager.cpp:133@operator()] Failed to start as either binder or ashmem kernel drivers are not loaded
```

```
$ anbox system-info
version: 4
snap-revision: 186
cpu:
  arch:  x86
  brand: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8145U CPU @ 2.10GHz
  features: 
    - aes
    - sse4_1
    - sse4_2
    - avx
    - avx2
os:
  name: Ubuntu
  version: 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)
  snap-based: true
kernel:
  version: Linux version 6.5.0-25-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-054) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.41) #25-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb  7 14:58:39 UTC 2024
  binder: false
  ashmem: false
graphics:
  egl:
    vendor: Mesa Project
    version: 1.4 (DRI2)
    extensions:
      - EGL_ANDROID_native_fence_sync
      - EGL_CHROMIUM_sync_control
      - EGL_EXT_buffer_age
      - EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness
      - EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import
      - EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import_modifiers
      - EGL_IMG_context_priority
      - EGL_KHR_config_attribs
      - EGL_KHR_create_context
      - EGL_KHR_create_context_no_error
      - EGL_KHR_fence_sync
      - EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses
      - EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace
      - EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image
      - EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image
      - EGL_KHR_gl_texture_3D_image
      - EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image
      - EGL_KHR_image
      - EGL_KHR_image_base
      - EGL_KHR_image_pixmap
      - EGL_KHR_no_config_context
      - EGL_KHR_reusable_sync
      - EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context
      - EGL_EXT_pixel_format_float
      - EGL_KHR_wait_sync
      - EGL_MESA_configless_context
      - EGL_MESA_drm_image
      - EGL_MESA_image_dma_buf_export
      - EGL_NOK_texture_from_pixmap
      - EGL_WL_bind_wayland_display
  gles2:
    vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
    vendor: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 18.0.5
    extensions:
      - GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a
      - GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3
      - GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5
      - GL_APPLE_texture_max_level
      - GL_EXT_blend_func_extended
      - GL_EXT_blend_minmax
      - GL_EXT_buffer_storage
      - GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance
      - GL_EXT_color_buffer_float
      - GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture
      - GL_EXT_copy_image
      - GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
      - GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query
      - GL_EXT_draw_buffers
      - GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed
      - GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex
      - GL_EXT_frag_depth
      - GL_EXT_geometry_point_size
      - GL_EXT_geometry_shader
      - GL_EXT_gpu_shader5
      - GL_EXT_map_buffer_range
      - GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
      - GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean
      - GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp
      - GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box
      - GL_EXT_read_format_bgra
      - GL_EXT_robustness
      - GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects
      - GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch
      - GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix
      - GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks
      - GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical
      - GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size
      - GL_EXT_tessellation_shader
      - GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp
      - GL_EXT_texture_buffer
      - GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
      - GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array
      - GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
      - GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
      - GL_EXT_texture_rg
      - GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode
      - GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
      - GL_EXT_unpack_subimage
      - GL_INTEL_conservative_rasterization
      - GL_INTEL_performance_query
      - GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
      - GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
      - GL_KHR_context_flush_control
      - GL_KHR_debug
      - GL_KHR_no_error
      - GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior
      - GL_KHR_robustness
      - GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr
      - GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d
      - GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions
      - GL_NV_draw_buffers
      - GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments
      - GL_NV_image_formats
      - GL_NV_read_buffer
      - GL_NV_read_depth
      - GL_NV_read_depth_stencil
      - GL_NV_read_stencil
      - GL_OES_EGL_image
      - GL_OES_EGL_image_external
      - GL_OES_EGL_sync
      - GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
      - GL_OES_copy_image
      - GL_OES_depth24
      - GL_OES_depth_texture
      - GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map
      - GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed
      - GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex
      - GL_OES_element_index_uint
      - GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
      - GL_OES_geometry_point_size
      - GL_OES_geometry_shader
      - GL_OES_get_program_binary
      - GL_OES_gpu_shader5
      - GL_OES_mapbuffer
      - GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
      - GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box
      - GL_OES_required_internalformat
      - GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
      - GL_OES_sample_shading
      - GL_OES_sample_variables
      - GL_OES_shader_image_atomic
      - GL_OES_shader_io_blocks
      - GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation
      - GL_OES_standard_derivatives
      - GL_OES_stencil8
      - GL_OES_surfaceless_context
      - GL_OES_tessellation_point_size
      - GL_OES_tessellation_shader
      - GL_OES_texture_3D
      - GL_OES_texture_border_clamp
      - GL_OES_texture_buffer
      - GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array
      - GL_OES_texture_float
      - GL_OES_texture_float_linear
      - GL_OES_texture_half_float
      - GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
      - GL_OES_texture_npot
      - GL_OES_texture_stencil8
      - GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array
      - GL_OES_vertex_array_object
      - GL_OES_vertex_half_float
      - GL_OES_viewport_array
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Have you configured your system properly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267823/module-ashmem-doesnt-load-with-secure-boot-on-but-binder-does-load-with-se)

Comment: I do have secure boot, since i'm dualbooting from a separate ssd, the original one in the laptop has windows, so i wanna stay safe and protect my pc from rootkits.
Also if I had secure boot disabled I would've been on Arch by now.

Comment: So, if you have Secure Boot enabled (as you should), here's the question again: Have you signed the module, i. e. *have you configured your system properly?*

Comment: @giulix - I didn’t ask if you have secure boot enabled, that’s something I assumed was the case, since you want to use *ashmem*

Comment: @ChanganAuto I didn’t do anything to my system, i just saw that binderfs was in /dev/ but anbox says that i didn’t install it.